# In which language a BIOS is written?

Tags: cpu, bios, disassembly, instruction-set

As I understand, the BIOS code/bitstream that held in the ROM should be generic (work alongside with multiple CPU types or ISAs). In addition, I saw mentions in the web that claim to have the possibility to dump it's code (and to "disassemble" it).

So, in which language, instruction set or machine code is it written? Doesn't it need any kind of processor to perform its operations? If so I guess that it will use the external CPU, then how does it knows the specific instruction set of the employed one?

Maybe it has an internal processor?

Answer (score 3):

Motherboards are tailored to fit a given instruction set, and the BIOS firmware is written in a reasonable subset of that instruction set (there's a bit of wiggle room). You can't use an x86 motherboard with an ARM CPU, for example (and if there are such boards, they would have to be capable of handling multiple different instruction sets, and more importantly, system architectures).

The code does run on the "main" CPU - if you don't have a CPU inserted, BIOS will not work either. In fact, if you want to know more about how the very first steps in the bootup process work, just pick the free book on Intel Systems Architecture (for x86 and friends) - it will answer pretty much all your questions, including the more modern technologies like "how do you start a multi-threaded OS" or "how do you switch to protected mode" and "how do you make the CPU sleep".

As an example, early Intel CPUs started execution on address `0x000FFFF0h`. This maps directly to the BIOS ROM (there's no copying to RAM - it's just a mapping), so it simply starts executing the BIOS startup. More modern Intel CPUs start at a different address, but the basic principle is still the same.

Now, older IBM BIOS were very simple, and had to fit in a tiny amount of memory space, so they were usually written in pure assembly (and maybe machine code directly, but I don't think that's necessary, really - though I have done this while experimenting with the IBM/Intel PC architecture). However, there have also been e.g. fully graphical BIOS systems, which might have been written in C, for example. That said, C isn't much of a step-up from assembly *except* for its portability - and as we've seen, there's not much point in having a portable BIOS; all IBM PCs ran on x86 CPUs. The same goes for the next step in the boot, the OS loader - it had to fit in a tiny amount of memory space, so it was usually written in assembly - however, in anything a bit less ancient than the original IBM PC, they simply tend to initialize the bare minimum file system "drivers", and run from disk (floppy or HDD).

Comment: Exactly.  The instructions in BIOS is the first program the CPU runs at boot to provide a standard interface to the hardware.  Usually written in assembly and compiled to machine code

Comment: So, are you saying that a typical motherboard is totally tight, for example, only to x86? And, what do you mean by "a bit of wiggle room"?

Comment: @Reflection You don't really need *all* the instructions to handle BIOS operations. Two different Intel CPUs may still work if they fit.

Comment: I understand it, but the question is about the motherboard support for specific against multiple families of processor.

Comment: @Reflection It's rather specific - in part, simply because of the fact that different architectures will have different sockets anyway, so there's little point in having a one-size-fits-all BIOS. But I've already mentioned plenty about that in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

The bios for a motherboard is extremely unique to that motherboard.  You either need the experience of all the nuances of an intel processor or just pay some one to write the bios for you, there is a very very small list of companies that do this and you are better off just hiring them.  It will cost you lots of time and money either way (cheaper and faster if you hire them).  Naturally they most likely use C and asm as the programming languages.  Non-x86 dont use a bios they use a bootloader of some sort (redboot,u-boot,etc), so this is really intel/x86 specific.

The bios runs on the main x86 processor.  it is not some magic thing it is just a boot up program written for the main processor that sits in a flash.

Now if you have BMC (server class machine) then yes, that is likely an arm processor separate from the x86, but you know what, you got to the same folks you paid to do the bios and you pay them to do your bmc firmware too.  for the same reason.  experience which you will not be able to overcome in an affordable time frame.  here again most likely written in C and asm, but who knows except them.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS (Basic IO System), is like a new born, know only few basic things, in this case input output instructions. These instructions I believe are written directly in machine code for optimum performance. I think after the PC starts up the BIOS is copied to RAM to speed-up and possibly to allow changes. BIOS is CPU and, I believe, architecture specific.

Answer (score -2):

BIOS is hardware part and it is totally written in system level language like 'C' language and it operate by 1 and 0 bit which is nothing but a voltage of light.....